# How to distinguish time from am and pm in the value of a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following values.

```
var list = "09:05, 10:05, 12:30, 16:30 , ... , ..."
```

The type of values ​​in the list is a regular string, not an object.

Based on this value, I want to divide from 0 to 12 am and from 13 to 23 pm.

Therefore, the result I want is as follows.(If you check the log value)

```
var am = am 09:05 , am 10:05
var pm = pm 12:30 , pm 16:30
```

It may be a simple question, but it is a very difficult problem for me as a script novice.

Please help me.

Comment: `am` and `pm` should be sorted as well?

Comment: Yes, those are the values ​​to put in the <option> tag, so it would be nice if AM and PM were next to it.

Comment: @gurvinder372 for example, var am = am 09:05 , am 10:05 ...

Comment: btw, `pm 16:30` is a wrong value, because the hour goes from 1 to 12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `sort` function first

```
var sort = ( a, b ) => convertToMin( a ) - convertToMin( b ); 
var convertToMin = ( a ) => ( items = a.split( ":" ).map( Number ), items[ 0 ] * 60 + items[ 1 ] );
```

Now use `reduce` to segregate the array

```
var output = list.reduce( (a,b) =>  //using reduce to iterate, a is the accumulator and b is item in array for current iteration
   ( convertToMin(b) > 12*60 ? a.pm.push( b ) : a.am.push( b ), a ) ,
     { am :[], pm : [] }) ; //accumulator is initialized to { am :[], pm : [] }

output.am.sort( sort  );
output.pm.sort( sort  );
```

**Demo**

```js
var list = ["09:05", "10:05", "12:30", "16:30"];
var sort = (a, b) => convertToMin(a) - convertToMin(b);
var convertToMin = (a) => (items = a.split(":").map(Number), items[0] * 60 + items[1]);

var output = list.reduce((a, b) =>
  (convertToMin(b) > 12 * 60 ? a.pm.push(b) : a.am.push(b), a), {
    am: [],
    pm: []
  });

output.am.sort(sort);
output.pm.sort(sort);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: well answered. I was expecting something like this.The js way... :D

Comment: It will take a long time to understand this. The code is very deep and hard. @gurvinder372

Comment: Does the code work even though there are more values ​​in the list?

Comment: @won Yes, length of the list is not a consideration for this code. it should work when there are more values in the list.

Comment: If I do not know anything about yourself, try commenting here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'd do to solve this problem.

- Separate the values in the string into an array. I'd Google `javascript split string into array`. Nothing wrong with Googling stuff; even seasoned devs have to do it all the time! At least I do. :)
- Then create a `for` loop that goes through each element of the array. A good search for how to do that is `javascript for loop array`.
- Then for each element, split the string again (this time by the `:`).
- Then convert the first part into a number (`javascript convert string
  to integer`) and see whether it is bigger or smaller than 12.

Answer (score 2):

You could adjusted value with [am/pm time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) and sort it to the wanted array.

```js
function format(v) { return ('0' + v).slice(-2); }

function getM(t) {
    var v = t.split(':');
    return (v[0] < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm') + ' ' + [v[0] % 12 || 12, v[1]].map(format).join(':');
}

var list = '09:05, 10:05, 12:30, 16:30',
    am = [],
    pm = []
    result = { am: am, pm: pm };

list
    .split(', ')
    .map(getM)
    .forEach(function (s) {
        result[s.slice(0, 2)].push(s);
    });

console.log(am);
console.log(pm);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Many people gave me answers. I will also refer to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.split` method like this,

Updated without jQuery

```js
var list = "09:05, 10:05, 12:30, 16:30";
var options = list.split(',').map(time => {
  h = time.split(':')[0];
  return parseInt(h) >= 12 ? 'pm ' + time : 'am ' + time;
})
console.log(options);
```

Comment: I dont think adding a library like jquery is needed for such a simple function

Comment: Many people gave me answers. I will also refer to your answer.

Comment: @orangespark Absolutely. I was not using jQuery in my actual code. Thanks for the info. I edited the post.

Comment: Glad that was helpful:)

Answer (score 1):

`Split` the items using the appropriate separator, process them with a cycle then `join` them with the appropriate separator

```
var items = list.split(", ");
var ams = [];
var pms = [];

for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
    var isPM = ((list[index].substring(0, 2) >= 12);
    var currentArray = window[isPM ? "pms" : "ams"];
    var found = false;
    var val = (isPM ? "pm" : "am") + " " + items[index];
    for (var innerIndex = 0; (!found) && (innerIndex < currentArray.length); innerIndex++) {
        if (currentArray[innerIndex] > val) {
            found = true;
            currentArray.splice(innerIndex, 0, val);
        }
    }
    if (!found) currentArray.push(val);
}

var am = ams.join(" , ");
var pm = pms.join(" , ");
```